# jQuery: Get the ID of unchecked table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a table with checkboxes. This is sort of permission table. I wanted to get the ID of the row with unchecked checkbox.

[image]

**Scenario:** If I uncheck **field3** from **Permission1** and hit save button I wanted to get the Id of permission1 row and change the name attribute to false of unchecked checkbox. I believe I can change the name attribute But I'm getting all the row ids in my console.log.

This is what I tried:

```
    $("#savePermissionTable").click(function() {
      $("#permissionTable tr").each(function() {
        if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]
 [name="true"]:not(:checked)')){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        }
      })
    })
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 1</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 2</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="permissionTable">
    <tr id="1">
      <td>Permission 1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>Permission 2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to search different example but nothing helped much with the unchecked checkbox.Any help what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

My Code: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjynk7xh/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A selector, when passed into an `if` will always return `true`. So, instead, use `$(".selector").length`.  Additionally, I added the name attribute update.

```js
$("#savePermissionTable").click(function() {
  $("#permissionTable tr").each(function() {
    var unchecked = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"][name="true"]:not(:checked)');
    if (unchecked.length) {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
      unchecked.attr("name",false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/719media/bootstrap-table/bootstrap4/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 1</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 2</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">field 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="permissionTable">
    <tr id="1">
      <td>Permission 1</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>Permission 2</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="true" checked>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="text-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="savePermissionTable"> Save  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me learn something new :) It worked perfectly

Comment: @Raihan You're welcome.  If you could upvote/mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be this one.

```
$("#savePermissionTable").click(function() {
$("input[name='true']:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        var el = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        $(this).prop("name",false);
        console.log($(el).prop('id'));
})
});
```

You can check it in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjynk7xh/31/)